# Combine Spring specification with PostgreSQL for fuzzy matching

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, fuzzy-search

I have the following specification:

```
public static Specification<MyObject> withName(String name) {
    return (root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder)
        -> StringUtils.isEmpty(name)
        ? criteriaBuilder.and()
        : criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get(MyObject_.NAME), name);
}
```

This works exactly like I would expect it to work.
I am using PostgreSQL and to make the filter more easy I would like to combine the method above with PostgreSQL's similarity method ( and others ).

How can I achieve that?

Comment: You aren't. That isn't part of the JPA spec (and not even closely in the JPA criteria API). So you would need to include SQL snippets, which you probably need to wrap in your own custom `Expression` implementation.

Comment: Wouldn't it work with criteriabuilder.function(...) ?

Comment: You can try to make it work, depends on the postgres implementation. Nonetheless you need some customization as it isn't one of the default supported functions.